# Detect if all objects between two points are of same tag in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, raycasting

I am making a game where the floor consists of individual live and dead pixels. If a line of live pixels are drawn between the two points, you pass. If the line is broken, you cannot pass.

I would like to detect wether all objects between two points are of the same Tag. Here is a drawing to try and illustrate this:

[image]

At the moment, I have the following code that checks if the next "pixel" is live or dead using RayCasts:

```js
function Update () {

    var pixfwd = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.up  * Reach);
    var pixbwd = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.down  * Reach);
    var pixleft = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.left * Reach);
    var pixright = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.right * Reach);

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, pixfwd * Reach, Color.red, 0.1f);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, pixbwd * Reach, Color.green, 0.1f);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, pixleft * Reach, Color.yellow, 0.1f);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, pixright * Reach, Color.blue, 0.1f);

    Physics.Raycast (transform.position, pixfwd, pixhit);
    Physics.Raycast (transform.position, pixbwd, pixhit2);
    Physics.Raycast (transform.position, pixleft, pixhit3);
    Physics.Raycast (transform.position, pixright, pixhit4);


    if ( checkVision(pixhit)  || checkVision(pixhit2)  || checkVision(pixhit3)  || checkVision(pixhit4) ) { 
        nextisLive = true;
    }
    else
    {   
        nextisLive=false;
    }

}

function checkVision(pixhit:RaycastHit):boolean
{
    if ( pixhit != null && pixhit.collider != null && pixhit.collider.tag == "Live" )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

    if ( pixhit2 != null && pixhit2.collider != null && pixhit2.collider.tag == "Live" )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

    if ( pixhit3 != null && pixhit3.collider != null && pixhit3.collider.tag == "Live" )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

    if ( pixhit4 != null && pixhit4.collider != null && pixhit4.collider.tag == "Live" )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hmm...instead of going through all your "pixels" and performing raycasts to detect their neighbours, how about just storing this information in a 2D array, and iterating through it? It'll be faster (and in my opinion, more straightforward) to interpret the data algorithmically rather than relying on Unity's physics engine for this.

Comment: @Serlite Okay thanks - do you have an example for how to do this?

Comment: Sure, I can draft out an algorithmic approach as an answer if you think it'd be a useful alternative.

Comment: That would be a massive help, thanks.

Comment: To clarify, how large are the start and end point? Can their heights vary between 1 and the full height of the grid, or are they static? And if the points are taller than 1 pixel, does the path need to hit all pixels of the point to be considered valid, or just 1?

Comment: They are static - and im not sure what you mean by size. In the games sense, they are generators at each end of a floor consisting of many pixels (the grid in the picture). If you connect the two generators with live pixels, the energy can be transferred between them. (I have enemies in the level that can walk across the path of live pixels and turn them dead again, breaking the route).

Comment: Ah, okay. So any point of contact along the length of the generators is a valid connection? (As in, not all the pixels next to the generators on either end have to be live, just at least one of them?)

Comment: No, the two generators need to have a route of live pixels connecting them. Basically I need a way of detecting if Point A and Point B have a route of live pixels connecting them. If they don't then the level is still not complete. The picture shows a scenario where the level should be complete.

Comment: Er, I was just referring to the start and end points, directly adjacent to the generators. Those only need a single live pixel at each to be valid, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach to this problem which doesn't rely on Unity's physics system is to store your "pixel" objects in a 2D array, and iterate through the array to evaluate whether or not the live pixels form a continuous path from one side to the other.

*Note: This assumes that when you create/initialize your game, you store your pixel objects in the array correctly, reflective of their in-game arrangement. (ie. Representative of the rows and columns of the grid they form.)*

Here's an idea of how your path validation algorithm might look:

```js
var pixels : GameObject[,];

function Start()
{
    // Populate pixels array in here, or when you create the grid if the pixels are
    // created dynamically.
    //
    // Array should be initialized to new GameObject[GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT];
    //
    // For this approach, it can be helpful if you group your pixel GameObjects under
    // empty GameObjects that match the structure of the array, as this will make it
    // easier to populate.
    // (Only really applies if you the pixels are not created dynamically.)
}

// Accepts two parameters, which provide the top and bottom of the generator at each
// point.
// 
// (For example, a generator spanning between pixels 0 and 2 in width would be
// represented by new int[]{0, 2})
function CheckForClearPath(startPoint : int[], endPoint : int[])
{
    // For tracking live pixels in last and current column
    var prevColumn : boolean[] = new boolean[pixels[0].length];
    var currColumn : boolean[] = new boolean[pixels[0].length];
    InitializeArray(prevColumn);

    // Iterating through each column of grid
    var x : int = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < pixels.length; x++)
    {
        // Special cases for first and last column
        var isFirstColumn : boolean = (x == 0);
        var isLastColumn : boolean = (x == pixels.length - 1);

        // Iterating through each row of grid column, first to identify live pixels
        // adjacent to previous column's live pixels
        var y : int = 0;
        for (y = 0; y < pixels[x].length; y++)
        {
            if (prevColumn[x]) {
                currColumn[y] = (pixels[x][y].tag == "Live");
            }
            else {
                currColumn[y] = false;
            }
        }

        // Next, iterating through each row of grid column, to identify live pixels
        // adjacent to current column's live pixels
        // 
        // This is done by checking whether current pixel is live, then checking whether
        // next pixel has live tag
        for (y = 0; y < pixels[x].length - 1; y++)
        {
            if (currColumn[y]){
                currColumn[y + 1] = (pixels[x][y].tag == "Live");
            }
        }

        // Check if any pixels are recorded as alive in column - if not, it means that no
        // live pixels were adjacent to last columns live pixels, and path is broken.
        if (AreAllPixelsDead(currColumn)) {
            return false;
        }

        // If first column, check if pixels next to start point are live.
        if (isFirstColumn) {
            if (!DoesPathMeetPoint(startPoint, currColumn)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // If last column, check if pixels next to end point are live.
        if (isLastColumn) {
            if (!DoesPathMeetPoint(endPoint, currColumn)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Saving current column results in last column results
        for (x = 0; x < pixels.length; x++)
        {
            prevColumn[x] = currColumn[x];
        }
    }

    // If all goes well, path is valid
    return true;
}

function InitializeArray(arrayRef : boolean[]) {
    for (var i : int = 0; i < arrayRef.length; i++)
    {
        arrayRef[i] = true;
    }
}

function AreAllPixelsDead(arrayRef : boolean[]) {
    for (var i : int = 0; i < arrayRef.length; i++)
    {
        if (arrayRef[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function DoesPathMeetPoint(point : int[], columnPixels : boolean[]) {
    for (var i : int = 0; i < columnPixels.length; i++)
    {
        if (columnPixels[i] && i >= point[0] && i <= point[1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Basically, the algorithm goes through each column of the grid, and determines whether there are live pixels adjacent to the previous column's live pixels, and live pixels adjacent to those. Successfully passing this test means that the live pixels in the grid form at least one continuous path from one end to the other. (Then there are the couple special checks to make sure the path connects to the start and end points.)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

*Disclaimer: Code not tested, but the logic of the algorithm is there.*

Comment: Firstly, thanks for that. I am not sure how you say to approach the Start() function. The pixels are not generated dynamically. Can I simply find all objects with the floor pixels name? Also there are many errors at the moment - such as "length isn't a member of gameobject".

Comment: Finding them by name might be a bit of a complicated approach, since you still need to figure out which row/column each pixel is in. What may prove easier is to group each row of pixels under an empty GameObject, then group those rows under a single empty GameObject. Then, you can pass that top GameObject through a public reference into the script, and iterate through its transforms to build up the array. With regards to the errors...unfortunately, UnityScript is not my primary coding language, so I'll have to take a look at it again when I get to a computer with Unity on it.